# How to Use DotNetOpenAuth on my system for OpenID provider?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dotnetopenauth

I want to use DotNetOpenAuth framework for using OpenID Provider i have Downloaded Source file from DotNetOpenAuth site now i want to know how should i start the openID provider on my system..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to below link you can get exact idea about DotNetOenAuth...

[How to use OpenID providers with unique identifier URLs in ASP.NET MVC4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12878441/how-to-use-openid-providers-with-unique-identifier-urls-in-asp-net-mvc4)